# Сайт отдает неверную разметку. Python, aiohttp

Tags: python, парсер, bs4, aiohttp

Нужно спарсить интернет-магазин. Получаю название товара, ссылку на картинку, но не могу понять, почему в браузере я вижу блок div с классом, в котором лежат размеры, но когда я делаю запрос с кода, то этого класса там нету. Помогите, пожалуйста!
Сайт: https://nude-project.com/products/nude-ring-gold
Класс который я искал: variant-input-wrap product-variants-group swiper js-variant-slider swiper-initialized swiper-horizontal swiper-pointer-events swiper-backface-hidden

Использую aiocfscrape и bs4

Comment: <div class="variant-wrapper products-together js   product">

Comment: Спасибо, помогло